# Get a list of nodes/blocks that use a certain module?

Tags: upgrading

Complete drupal noob just got hired by a company, my first task is to update/upgrade. Not being familiar with their site, I don't know what nodes/blocks the modules hook into. I want to get the latest versions of core and all of their modules, but I don't want to break anything, and I don't want to have to crawl the whole site to check if anything is broken. Advice? Is there a way to list the nodes and blocks that use a given module?

TLDR; Is there a way to get a list of pages given the module name and providing a list of nodes/blocks/other that use that module?

Comment: Drupal isn't structured like that I'm afraid; a module might provide functionality to all sorts of system entities depending on settings/other modules installed/all sorts of other conditions, and it might do so in very subtle ways (i.e. ways that no amount of automation will be able to help you discover). Your best bet...take a dev copy of the site, install drush, upgrade core and contrib modules, then test, test, test

Comment: @clive thanks for the clarification. So, do you have other ideas/strategies for me to ensure that the updates don't break anything?

Comment: There's no easy answer to that really; I'd advise installing the [Hacked!](http://drupal.org/project/hacked/) module, it'll tell you if the previous developer has changed any of the core/contributed modules (very bad practice but it does happen). If there have been any changes those will obviously be overwritten and whatever problem(s) they were changed to solve will rear up again, so you'll need to manually merge the patches again.

Comment: Other than that it really is a matter of just testing the major functionality of the site to see if the upgrades have broken anything. If you're lucky the old developer will have written some tests to help with that